# How to count objects in JSON and check for false statements in those

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

```json
{
   "players":[
      [
         "Marta86",
         23,
         252162,
         "https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/fb/fb7e45fb629ddfa2fdc6d39ed2ed9cd9e4d7b124_medium.jpg",
         false,
         "Garbage Collector",
         false
      ],
      [
         "Davidsta_",
         19,
         535731,
         false,
         false,
         "Train Conductor",
         false
      ]
   ],
   "server":{
      "region":"EU",
      "number":"4",
      "name":"Compatibility Version",
      "limit":512,
      "uptime":"16h 03m",
      "dxp":[
         false
      ],
      "beta":"",
      "motd":""
   }
}
```

I want to read the JSON, make it count the amount of players, as well as count the 5th item in a player (in this case both false) to see if it is true (as it is server staff), and if it is true, it adds 1 to the variable named `s1Staff`.

How can I do this? I have tried looking to see if it is possible to count it but I have not found any good explanation for it. I am quite new to programming, so sorry if I use any incorrect terms.

Comment: Like many questions on Stack Overflow, this isn't actually about JSON. You have some text in a file that you can parse using `json.load`, and now you have a regular Python data. Most of your question is how to interact with the resulting `dict`.

Answer (score 0):

If the data is in a file named `players.json`, then you can do the following:

```py
import json

with open('./players.json', 'r') as f:
    data = json.load(f) # data is now a Python dictionary
players_count = len(data['players'])
s1Staff = sum([1 for i in data['players'] if i[6]])
```

In this case, `players_count = 2` and `s1Staff = 0`

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this. There are other ways

```
import json
JS = '''{
    "players": [
        [
            "Marta86",
            23,
            252162,
            "https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/fb/fb7e45fb629ddfa2fdc6d39ed2ed9cd9e4d7b124_medium.jpg",
            false,
            "Garbage Collector",
            false
        ],
        [
            "Davidsta_",
            19,
            535731,
            false,
            false,
            "Train Conductor",
            false
        ]
    ],
    "server": {
        "region": "EU",
        "number": "4",
        "name": "Compatibility Version",
        "limit": 512,
        "uptime": "16h 03m",
        "dxp": [
            false
        ],
        "beta": "",
        "motd": ""
    }
}'''

J = json.loads(JS)

print(f'Number of players = {len(J["players"])}')
print(f'True count = {len([None for p in J["players"] if p[4]])}')
```